# How do get more control over loop increments in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to loop from 0 to 1 using step sizes of 0.01 (for example). How would I go about doing this? The `for i in range(start, stop, step)` only takes integer arguments so floats won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
for i in [float(j) / 100 for j in range(0, 100, 1)]:
    print i
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the last printed value here is 0.99, and not 1.0, but this is only because the last value returned by `range` is 99 and not 100.

Comment: If you want 0.00 to 1.00 inclusive, then use: `range(0, 101, 1)`.

Comment: Note that this has no reason not to use a generator comprehension, i.e. using parentheses as in `for i in (float(j) / 100 for j in range(100)):` -- this creates a lazy generator rather than building a whole list before even starting the loop.

Answer (score 6):

Avoid compounding floating point errors with this approach.  The number of steps is as expected, while the value is calculated for each step.

```
def drange2(start, stop, step):
    numelements = int((stop-start)/float(step))
    for i in range(numelements+1):
            yield start + i*step
Usage:

for i in drange2(0, 1, 0.01):
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
            yield start
            start += step
```

Usage:

```
for i in drange(0, 1, 0.01):
    print i
```

Comment: -1: This could have a problem if the `step` cannot be exactly represented by a floating point number. For example the last element for `drange(0,13,0.13)` is 12.870000000000024 (**100** elements), and the last element for `drange(0,11,0.11)` is  10.999999999999995 (**101** elements).

Comment: Even simpler: `list(drange(0,10,1))` looks like it behaves like `range`: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` but `list(drange(0,1,0.1))` gives an extra element: `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehensions either:

```
print([i for i in [float(j) / 100 for j in range(0, 100, 1)]])
```

if you want control over printing i then do something like so:

```
print(['something {} something'.format(i) for i in [float(j) / 100 for j in range(0, 100, 1)]])
```

or

```
list(i for i in [float(j) / 100 for j in range(0, 100, 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best way is using numpy array.

If you want to to loop from -2 thru +2 with increment of 0.25 then this is how I would do it:

```
Start = -2
End = 2
Increment = 0.25
Array =  np.arange(Start, End, Increment)

for i in range(0, Array.size):
    print (Array[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make your loop go from 0 to 100 with a step the size of 1 which will give you the same amount of steps. Then you can divide i by 100 for whatever you were going to do with it.

Comment: @James Yes, we could also just make an infinite while loop, and maintain the counters inside the loop. However, I'm trying to learn Python and I figured this would be good to know.

Comment: One issue here is that initializing a variable to 0.0 and adding 0.01 to it 100 times will not necessarily result in exactly 1.0.  So the "right" way to do this depends a lot on how the values are to be used.

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss - first thing you need to learn is that floats are not as exact as you may expect them to be. Sort of. Go to the Python interpreter, type 'a = 0.4' then enter, then type 'a' and enter.

Answer (score -1):

your code

```
for i in range(0,100,0.01):
```

can be achieved in a very simple manner instead of using float

```
for i in range(0,10000,1):
```

if you are very much concerned with float then you can go with
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935466/2225357

Comment: After that, use `dec = float(i)/100` inside for loop, if you still want the decimal value