# Making a list of evenly spaced numbers in a certain range in python

Tags: list, range, python

What is a pythonic way of making list of arbitrary length containing evenly spaced numbers (not just whole integers) between given bounds? For instance:

```
my_func(0,5,10) # ( lower_bound , upper_bound , length )
# [ 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5 ]
```

Note the `Range()` function only deals with integers. And this:

```
def my_func(low,up,leng):
    list = []
    step = (up - low) / float(leng)
    for i in range(leng):
        list.append(low)
        low = low + step
    return list
```

seems too complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: There was some nice solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Comment: Note that this only works accurately for some sequences due to the (necessary) inaccuracy of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Given numpy, you could use [linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy-linspace):

Including the right endpoint (5):

```
In [46]: import numpy as np
In [47]: np.linspace(0,5,10)
Out[47]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.55555556,  1.11111111,  1.66666667,  2.22222222,
        2.77777778,  3.33333333,  3.88888889,  4.44444444,  5.        ])
```

Excluding the right endpoint:

```
In [48]: np.linspace(0,5,10,endpoint=False)
Out[48]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```

Comment: @Double AA: True; if you need a list, you could use `np.linspace(0,5,10).tolist()`.

Answer (score 53):

You can use the following approach:

```
[lower + x*(upper-lower)/length for x in range(length)]
```

lower and/or upper must be assigned as floats for this approach to work.

Comment: Nice to have a concise stock python alternative in case numpy is not available.

Comment: this updated version produces the _exact_ same output as numpy linspace:
`[lower + x*(upper-lower)/(length-1) for x in range(length)`

Comment: @Trav it does not provide the exact same. The results are not numerically identical for when ascending linspace, and for descending (example: np.linspace(1,0.2,4)) it is very off. Still, its a good effort to get same ballpark numbers for ascending case

Answer (score 14):

Similar to unutbu's answer, you can use numpy's arange function, which is analog to Python's intrinsic function `range`. Notice that the end point is not included, as in `range`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(0,5, 0.5)
>>> a
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
>>> a = np.arange(0,5, 0.5) # returns a numpy array
>>> a
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
>>> a.tolist() # if you prefer it as a list
[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
```

Comment: Or simply:
a = N.arange(0, 5 , 0.5).tolist()

Comment: Careful when using numpy.arange(), though, endpoints are not handled consistently, giving rise to unreliable behavior, see [here](http://quantumwise.com/forum/index.php?topic=110.0).

Comment: for integers, np.arange(0, 5, 1).

and

for floating numbers, np.arange(0, 5, 1.0)

Answer (score 4):

```
f = 0.5
a = 0
b = 9
d = [x * f for x in range(a, b)]
```

would be a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's [`r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) convenience function can also create evenly spaced lists with syntax `np.r_[start:stop:steps]`. If `steps` is a real number (ending on `j`), then the end point is included, equivalent to `np.linspace(start, stop, step, endpoint=1)`, otherwise not.

```
>>> np.r_[-1:1:6j, [0]*3, 5, 6]
array([-1. , -0.6, -0.2,  0.2,  0.6,  1.])
```

You can also directly concatente other arrays and also scalars:

```
>>> np.r_[-1:1:6j, [0]*3, 5, 6]
array([-1. , -0.6, -0.2,  0.2,  0.6,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  5. ,  6. ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the folowing code:

```
def float_range(initVal, itemCount, step):
    for x in xrange(itemCount):
        yield initVal
        initVal += step

[x for x in float_range(1, 3, 0.1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Howard's answer but a bit more efficient:

```
def my_func(low, up, leng):
    step = ((up-low) * 1.0 / leng)
    return [low+i*step for i in xrange(leng)]
```