# Pandas groupby and sample evenly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This question is similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683690/making-a-list-of-evenly-spaced-numbers-in-a-certain-range-in-python), but applied to pandas

`df = pd.DataFrame({'tid': [0]*44 + [2]*66, 'fidx': list(range(44)) + list(range(66))})`

I need to sample 10 'fidx' per 'tid' such that each fidx is futhers apart.
I figure out how to do it like this; however, I think this can be done with `df.groupby` and some other functions but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
def sampling(df):
    mins = df['tid'].drop_duplicates().index
    maxes = df['tid'].drop_duplicates(keep='last').index
    frames = []
    for mi, ma in zip(mins, maxes):
        frames.append([mi + int(x*(ma-mi)/10) for x in range(10)])

    frames = list(chain(*frames))
    return frames
```

The  worst part is having to flatten the list at the end.

Expected output
`df.iloc[frames, :]`

```
     tid  fidx
0      0     0
4      0     4
8      0     8
12     0    12
17     0    17
21     0    21
25     0    25
30     0    30
34     0    34
38     0    38
44     2     1
50     2    14
57     2    21
63     2    27
70     2    34
76     2    40
83     2    47
89     2    53
96     2    60
102    2    66
```

10 fidx for each tid and the fidx are as evenly separated as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way. `groupby` + `cumcount` gives a numbering to `fidx` in each group. Then `groupby` + `count` values divided by 10 gives the spacing between numbers. Then we index the modulo 0 of these numbers:

```
g = df.groupby(['tid'])['fidx']
out = df[g.cumcount().mod(g.transform('count').div(10).round(0)) == 0]
```

Output:

```
     tid  fidx
0      0     0
4      0     4
8      0     8
12     0    12
16     0    16
20     0    20
24     0    24
28     0    28
32     0    32
36     0    36
40     0    40
44     2     0
51     2     7
58     2    14
65     2    21
72     2    28
79     2    35
86     2    42
93     2    49
100    2    56
107    2    63
```