# Trying to find smallest number

Tags: python, numbers

In my program I'm trying to find the smallest number that python can give me. When I kept dividing a number by 2, I got 5 x 10^-324 (5e-324). I thought I could divide this by the biggest number I can use in python. I tried to get the biggest number in python by doing this:

```
z = 1
    while True:
        try:
            z = z+1
        except OverflowError:
            z = z-1
            break
```

---

Here is my full code:

```
from os import system
x = 76556758478567587
while True:
    x = x/2
    if x/2 == 0.0:
        break

print("Smallest number I can compute:", x)
print()
z = 1
while True:
    try:
        z = z+1
    except OverflowError:
        z = z-1
        break

print(str(x) + " divided by " + str(z) + " is...")
z = x/z
print(z)
system("pause >nul")
```

Every time I run this it does nothing. I suddenly recognize it's still trying to solve the problem so I open task manager and Python was eating up my CPU like a pack of wolves eating a dead cow.

---

I know the smallest number in python would be negative but I want to get the the smallest number **above zero**.

Comment: Find the largest integer first, then take the reciprocal;)

Comment: you first algorithm is log(N)-complex, your second one is N-complex. You should multiply by 2 until you reach overflow THEN work your way down. However I'm sensing that the exercise is pointless.

Comment: What? There is no maximum or minimum number in Python. Python will automagically convert your "int" to a "long" which is actually infinite size (realistically w.e. is allocated by the OS). There is a max 'int', but it's fairly meaningless. If that's not satisfying, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic or search for "big number library" for reference impls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `sys.float_info` to get the maximum/minimum representable finite float as:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.min
2.2250738585072014e-308
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Python uses double-precision floats, which can hold values from about 10 to the -308 to 10 to the 308 power. Below is the experiment from the python prompt:

```
# for maximum
>>> 1e308
1e+308
>>> 1e+309
inf   <-- Infinite
```

You may even get numbers smaller than `1e-308` via [`denormals`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), but there is a significant performance hit to this and such numbers are *represented with a loss of precision*. I found that Python is able to handle 1e-323 but underflows on 1e-324 and returns 0.0 as the value.

```
# for minimum
>>> 1e-323
1e-323
>>> 1e-324
0.0
```

You can get denormalized minimum as `sys.float_info.min * sys.float_info.epsilon`, which comes as **`5e-324`**.

As per the document:

> **sys.float_info.max** is maximum representable finite float
>
> **sys.float_info.min** is minimum positive normalized float

To get more information check: [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

> **sys.float_info** is a struct sequence holding information about the float type. It contains low level information about the precision and internal representation. The values correspond to the various floating-point constants defined in the standard header file float.h for the ‘C’ programming language; see section 5.2.4.2.2 of the 1999 ISO/IEC C standard [C99], ‘Characteristics of floating types’, for details.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it seems that you _can_ still divide `sys.float_info.min` ... And I'm not sure _why_.  Maybe an IEEE guru can enlighten us?

Comment: How do you suppose that 2.2250738585072014e-308 is the smallest available float when the OP has gotten to 5e-324?

Comment: Try: `sys.float_info.min*sys.float_info.epsilon`

Comment: @mgilson isn't this about normalized and unnormalized floats? `2.2e-308` might be divided into `0.000000002e-308`, etc?

Comment: @AndrasDeak -- Likely.  I don't know the difference between a "normalized" and "unnormalized" float :-).  You'd think I would have picked that up somewhere ...

Comment: @mgilson and I don't even know the terminology, apparently they're called [denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number).

Comment: In order to clarify the doubts here: `sys.float_info.max` is the number with the largest exponent and the full precision in use. As you go above it, you'll loose precision. Similar is for `.min`

Comment: Python uses double-precision floats, which can hold values from about 10 to the -308 to 10 to the 308 power. Updated the answer with the experiment from the python prompt. Hope that will clarify your doubt

Comment: This answer was most helpful because I tried the code and divided what I got with the maximum float. I got 0, this confirmed that I had found the smallest number (above 0) in python. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest floating point number representable in Python is `5e-324`, or `2.0**-1075`.

The other two answers have each given you half of what you need to find this number. It can be found by multiplying `sys.float_info.min` (`2.2250738585072014e-308`, the smallest normalized float) by `sys.float_info.epsilon` (`2.220446049250313e-16`, the smallest proportion you can modify a number by while still getting a distinct value).

Answer (score 0):

The key word that you're apparently missing is "[epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon)."  If you search on **Python epsilon value** then it returns a links to [StackOverflow: Value for epsilon in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9528486/149076) near the top of the results in Google.

Obviously it helps if you understand how the term is associated with this concept.