# sklearn (ver 0.24) MAPE -- what is eps? (

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand sklearn's new [MAPE function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error). It is mentioned in the documentation that

> we do not represent the output as a percentage in range [0, 100]. Instead, we represent it in range [0, 1/eps]. Read more in the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-absolute-percentage-error).

What is eps? And how can I possibly convert the values obtained from this MAPE to percentage?

[sklearn MAPE documentation formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shYn7.png%5D)

Comment: Related: [Value for epsilon in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9528421/11082165) and [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Answer (score 1):

The User Guide link that you already know about explains that "ε is an arbitrary small yet strictly positive number to avoid undefined results when y is zero", but it doesn't state what that value actually is.

You can find the definition [in the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/825388fa755e1c47a3e8d60bbed34ae5fea8c756/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L350) to be:

```
    epsilon = np.finfo(np.float64).eps
```

which is the smallest positive 64 bit floating point number such that `1 + eps ≠ 1`.  The value is 2⁻⁵² ≈ 2.22e-16.  (See the documentation for [`numpy.finfo`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) for more information.)

To convert to a percentage, just multiply the return value of `mean_absolute_percentage_error` by 100.

---

*Note:* The comment "we do not represent the output as a percentage in range [0, 100]" is potentially misleading.  When expressed as a percentage by multiplying by 100, the MAPE will not necessarily be in the range [0, 100].  For example, if the data is, say, `y_true = [1, 1, 1]` and `y_pred = [1, 4, 2.5]`, the MAPE computed by

```
mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

is 1.5, which expressed as a percentage is 150%.  I think the intent of the comment is to make clear that--despite what the name might imply--they don't multiply by 100, so the result is a fraction, not a percentage.  That fraction can certainly be greater than 1, and so the percentage can be greater than 100.