# How to use float variable with range function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

**Description:**
I have three variable a, x and y. I want to apply the following, if variable a in range(x, y) print the a variable

**Code:**

```
a = "0.50"
x = "-14.40"
y = "0.50"

for a in range(int(x), int(y)):
    print a
```

**Error** (of course):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-14.40'
```

Pythonista i need your help here please!!

Comment: What is wrong with `<` and `>` ?

Comment: Surely you just need `float()` rather than int?

Comment: yes you're totally right @DanielRoseman but like you know range don't support float rather than int number

Comment: Can't you use them like -14 rather than "-14"?

Comment: `range` is not intended to be used in this way. Why don't you simply check `if a >= x and a <= y: # then do something`.

Comment: `if float(x) <= float(a) <= float(y):`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want that code to do. Do you want it to print all the integers between -14.40 and 0.5 ?

Comment: You may want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267226/range-for-floats/7267806

Comment: It looks like you want to go from `x` to `y` in steps of 0.5. You can't use `range()` for that, it is for integers. Write a loop and do the addition yourself.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `range` function?

Comment: @BoarGules Where do you get that "steps of 0.5"? I suspect that the OP doesn't actually want to do any looping at all...

Comment: @PM2Ring i need to check if a in range of x and y or not.

Comment: So you're just checking a single `a` value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49071749/6260170 ?

Comment: @PM2Ring It looked to me as if what he actually wanted to do was `for a in range(-14.4,0.5,0.5):`. But it appears his misunderstanding of `range()` was even more fundamental than I imagined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 2 `range` function is irrelevant for this task. You just need to convert those strings to floats and do simple comparison tests. Eg,

```
a = "0.50"
x = "-14.40"
y = "0.50"

afloat = float(a)
if float(x) <= afloat and afloat <= float(y):
    print a
```

**output**

```
0.50
```

This can be written more simply (and more efficiently) using Python's comparison chaining.

```
a = "0.50"
x = "-14.40"
y = "0.50"

if float(x) <= float(a) <= float(y):
    print a
```

---

FWIW, in Python 3, the `range` object *can* be useful for testing membership of a range, but it wouldn't be useful for your case. Eg,

```
>>> r = range(1, 10, 2)
>>> list(r)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> 3 in r
True
>>> 4 in r
False
>>> 3.5 in r
False
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments

> i need to check if a in range of x and y or not.

Then do

```
a = "0.50"
x = "-14.40"
y = "0.50"

if float(x) <= float(a) <= float(y):  # checks a is between x and y (inclusive)
     # do something
```

`range` does something very different. It is for making iterators which we can use in `for` loops, like this:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(i * 2)
0
2
4
6
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy arange.

```
import numpy as np
r = np.arange(-14.4,0.5, 0.5)

def isinside(x):
if x in r:
    print ("x")
else:
    print ("x no in a")

isinside(-12)
```

returns

```
x no in a
```

If you want to print the whole serie

```
print ([round(x) for x in r])# round to avoid long numbers
```

Some more information https://pynative.com/python-range-for-float-numbers/