# How can i get a range of floats in python?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1.5,21):
    print(i)
```

Whenever i run this code i get an error:

`TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Is there any built in modules for getting a range of floats?

Comment: What would you want range() to return for floats? There are infinite floats in between any 2 numbers (that arent the same number)

Comment: You can to range with integers (no possible with floats) and, inside loop, obtain the floats you want from the corresponding integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [range() for floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267226/range-for-floats)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know how many values you'd like to divide the range `1.5, 21` into, `numpy.linspace` will do the job:

```
import numpy

for i in numpy.linspace(1.5,21,num=10):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
$ python main.py
1.5
3.6666666666666665
5.833333333333333
8.0
10.166666666666666
12.333333333333332
14.5
16.666666666666664
18.833333333333332
21.0
```

Or if you'd rather go by step than number of output values, you can use `numpy.arange`:

```
import numpy

for i in numpy.arange(1.5,21,step=0.5):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
$ python main.py
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
[-- cut --]
19.0
19.5
20.0
20.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a `range` of `float`s. Think about it. Can a computer do one and a half (1.5) of a task? If you simply want to give it a float and round it up (or down) then use `round()` function, this will round the float to an `int`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an optimal solution for you but ***be aware*** that this code can return sometimes bad results ! as duplicating elements or even missing some !!!

```
def frange(*args):
    
    ((res:=[],gdigits:=lambda n,r:len(str(n)[::-1].split('.')[0])if'.'in str(n)else r,chf:=lambda n:True if type(n)==float else False),
    ((len(args)==0)and(
        a:=0.,
        b:=10.,
        c:=1.)),        
    ((len(args)==1)and((chf(args[0])and(
        a:=0.,
        b:=args[0]*1.,
        c:=1/10**gdigits(args[0],0))
        )or(
        a:=0,
        b:=args[0],
        c:=10**gdigits(args[0],0)))),       
    ((len(args)==2)and((any(map(lambda x: True if int(x)!=x else False,args))and(
        a:=args[0]*1.,
        b:=args[1]*1.,
        c:=1/10**max(gdigits(a,len(str(a))),gdigits(b,len(str(b)))))
        )or(
        a:=args[0],
        b:=args[1],
        c:=1))),
    ((len(args)==3)and((any(map(lambda x: True if int(x)!=x else False,args))and(
        a:=args[0]*1.,
        b:=args[1]*1.,
        c:=args[2]*1. if args[2]!=0 else 1)
        )or(
        a:=args[0],
        b:=args[1],
        c:=args[2] if args[2]!=0 else 1)))
        )   
    res.append(a)
    (a<b and [res.append(a:=round(a+c,len(str(c)[::-1].split('.'))if'.'in str(c)else 0)) for _ in iter(lambda:a<b,0)])
    (b<a and [res.append(a:=round(a-c,len(str(c)[::-1].split('.'))if'.'in str(c)else 0)) for _ in iter(lambda:b<a,0)])      
    return (i for i in res)

print('****    Test Cases    ****\n')
print(f'no args: {list(frange())}\n')
print(f'float arg: {list(frange(0.58))}\n')
print(f'int arg: {list(frange(10))}\n')
print(f'2  float args: {list(frange(1.11,1.3))}\n')
print(f'reversed 2 float args: {list(frange(1.3,1.11))}\n')
print(f'2 int args: {list(frange(3,8))}\n')
print(f'reversed 2 int args: {list(frange(8,3))}\n')
print(f'3 float args: {list(frange(1.75,3.4,0.05))}\n')
print(f'reversed 3 float args: {list(frange(3.4,1.75,0.05))}\n')
print(f'3 int args: {list(frange(2,11,3))}\n')
print(f'reversed 3 int args: {list(frange(11,2,3))}\n')
print(f'mixed 1: {list(frange(3,12.4,0.2))}\n')
print(f'mixet 2: {list(frange(12,1,1.2))}\n')
```