# These functions look like they'd do the same thing, but one works and one doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, function

New to coding. Need a function that checks whether a number is in a given range (inclusive of high and low)

My attempted solution:

```
def ran_check(num,low,high):
    if num >= low and num <= high:
        print(f'{num} is in between the range {low} and {high}')
    else:
        print(f'{num} is not in between the range {low} and {high}')
```

The correct solution:

```
def ran_check(num,low,high):
    if num in range(low,high+1):
        print(f'{num} is in between the range {low} and {high}')
    else:
        print(f'{num} is not in between the range {low} and {high}')
```

No syntax error on either one, but calling the function using the first returns nothing. Why won't the first one work, aren't they the same thing?

***UPDATE*** The issue was with how I was using Jupyter Notebooks, not the code itself. Thanks for the helpful feedback and tips to write this cleaner!

Comment: What are you expecting it to return precisely?

Comment: Both functions work for me, are you sure you aren't doing something else?

Comment: @Turksarama there are some edge cases

Comment: 0.5 is not in between the range 0 and 1

Comment: expecting: ran_check(6,4,12) to return '6 is in between the range 4 and 12.' Works for the second piece of code but not the first. Using it in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `ran_check(6,4,12)` does work on both, are you sure you are not overwriting the functions? Notebooks can be evil with their global scope.

Comment: A clearer way to write this would be `if low <= num <= high:`. This would include `float`s and `int`s

Comment: Ivan seems to be right. This appears to be an issue within Jupyter Notebooks, not with the code itself.

Comment: Both functions indeed "return None", by the way

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  "Doesn't work" is not a problem specification, especially when neither code block does anything.

Answer (score 0):

If `num` is a floating point number it won't work. Checking if it is in `range(low, high + 1)` checks to see if it is in `[low, low + 1, ..., high]`, elementwise.

Checking if `num >= low` and `num <= high` checks the actual numerical value

Comment: Or `low <= num <= high`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what different behaviour you encounter, but one thing that is different is their relation to floating-point numbers. the range() function creates an array of integers from a low number to a high number, with a step that is an integer as well.

This means that when you check if a number is "in range()" it will check only if it's a part of the integers between those two numbers, whereas a simple range check (>=, <=), will return the correct result for floats as well.

Comment: range() returns a generator of numbers, `step` apart, not strictly integers

Comment: range() can only take integers as arguments, at least as far as I know, so I see no combination that will not make it output integers.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267226/range-for-floats But still doesn't return an array

Comment: That''s correct, I just thought the difference isn't relevant to the question...

Answer (score 0):

A clearer way to write this would be:

```
def ran_check(num,low,high):
    is_or_not = 'is' if low <= num <= high else 'is not'
    print(f'{num} {is_or_not} in between the range {low} and {high}')
```

This will include floats and ints