# TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python-3.x

I got following error in my python program. can anyone resolve this problem?

```
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)  


a=2
b=3
c=7
d=6.23
if (a+b)==(c+d):
    print("Results")
else:
    for i in range (int(0.0,10.0,0.01)):
     a=3+i;
     if (a+b)==(c+d):
         print(i)
         break
```

Comment: What did you expect `int(0.0, 10.0, 0.01)` to return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [range() for floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267226/range-for-floats)

Comment: I want to equalize the equation (a+b) = (c+d) for given input values and a= 3+i, here i value in range between 0 and 10 @Selcuk

Comment: my expected output should be i  = 7.22