# Can 'n' be a float in the case of 'i in range of 1, n'

Tags: python-3.x, range, perfect-numbers

I'm new to python3 (and coding in general) and was working on a code that finds perfect numbers.
e.g. 28 is a perfect number so when I was looking for all the integers this number is dividable by
I found out that I only have to look at integers ranging from 1 to the root of 28. This worked but I don't understand how a range can go to the root of 28 because that isn't an integer.

I wondered if it ignores everything after the comma or rounds to the nearest integer but I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet. Does anyone know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267226/range-for-floats

Comment: `import math; for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(28))): ...`