# standard deviation in python - float object not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to find the standard deviation of numbers in python.  This is an entry level programming class so i am avoiding trying to use a function since they have not been introduced yet.

This program allows me to add numbers to a list, analyze said list, and then bring out the average, min, max, STDev, ect.  I have managed to successfully display everything except STDev, the error i keep getting is float object not iterable.  here is the code for the related part:

```
elif (menuchoice == 4):
        sum = 0.0
        print("std deviation")
        stdev = 0.0
        for i in range(listcount):
            scorenum4 = eval(scorenum[i])
            scoreaverage2 += scorenum4
        scoreaverage2 /= listcount
        for i in range(listcount):
            stdev = []
            scorenum3 = eval(scorenum[i])
            stdev += (scorenum3 - scoreaverage2)**2
            dev = sqrt((stdev)/listcount-1)
        print(dev)
```

any help would be geat, thank you.

-Self edit - I just removed stdev=[] out of my for loop, not sure why it was there - I am getting an answer now, but it is mathematically off

- Changed to dev = sqrt((stdev)/listcount) and it fixed my math error, DSM confirmed this fix as well. Thank you
- Program is functioning properly now! woot. Thank you everyone for the advise.

Comment: It's always better to include the traceback.

Comment: `eval()`? Surely `float()` would be a better choice!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Comment: Be sure to accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 5):

That's a very long winded way of calculating the standard deviation. This is a more pythonic way, and I dare say it's also more readable.

```
mean = sum(scorenum, 0.0) / len(scorenum)
d = [ (i - mean) ** 2 for i in scorenum]
std_dev = math.sqrt(sum(d) / len(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `stdev = []`, which just does not make any sense (according to your edit you already did this, but it is still in the code).

Second, move the line `dev = sqrt(stdev/(listcount-1))` out of the for loop (decrease the level of indentation). This should be done only once after the terms have been added up. *Edit:* Also fix the parentheses, as pointed out by @DSM.

Comment: I will try moving it out of the loop, because I understand what you are saying, but it appears to be working now within the loop. thank you

Comment: @anotherfiz It works because you overwrite the value from the previous iteration each time. Still, if I had to judge on your assignment I would at least put a big questionmark next to that line. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical error in your code is here:

```
        dev = sqrt((stdev)/listcount-1)
```

You want either `dev = sqrt(stdev/listcount)` or `dev = sqrt(stdev/(listcount-1))`, depending on your d.o.f. preference.  After I fix this, your (modified) code seems to work.

Comment: Thank you - changing the code to your first recommendation seems to have fixed my mathematical error

Answer (score 0):

Another answer proposes a more pythonic way of doing, but I propose here a correction.
It is not as efficient, but the classical algorithm is more understandable for a beginner.

Say scorenum is the array storing data from which you need and STD.

```
import math
average=0.0
for ii in scorenum: # iterate the data array, it can contain float
    sum+=ii
average/=float(len(scorenum)) # number of data=array length

# now, compute an estimator of std=sqrt(variance/n), where variance=sum((xi-xavg)**2)
std=0.0
for ii in scorenum:
    std+=(ii-average)**2
std=math.sqrt(std/float(len(scorenum))) # if you prefer n-1: std/float(len(scorenum)-1)

print "average=",average," std=",std
```

Comments:
- you can iterate any kind of array
- you must import math library
- operators like += and /= are here for fancyness. They are equivalent to sum=sum+ii, average=average/....