# Cycle "for" in python like in C

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python decimal range() step value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value)

I have a cycle in C:

```
for (float i = 0; i < 2 * CONST; i += 0.01) {
    // ... do something
}
```

I need the same cycle in python, but:

```
for x in xxx
```

not the same.

How can i make it in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost on the line. This is how you do it on a list: -

```
your_list = [1, 2, 3]
for eachItem in your_list:
    print eachItem
```

If you want to iterate over a certain range: -

```
for i in xrange(10):
    print i
```

To give a step value you can use a third parameter, so in your case it would be: -

```
for i in xrange(2 * CONST, 1):
    print i
```

But you can only give an `integer` value as step value.

If you want to use `float` increment, you would have to modify your range a little bit:-

```
for i in xrange(200 * CONST):
    print i / 100.0
```

Comment: I suggest range in favor of xrange because range actually creates an array wasting space

Comment: Thx, you gave me a point how to do that.

Comment: @MrSil. You're welcome :) You should take the update code. I mistakenly wrote incorrect range in the last code. Corrected now. :)

Comment: @Rohit Jain already solved my problem, thx.

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in xrange(200*CONST):
    i = i/100.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Write your own **range generator**. This helps you deal with non-integer step values with ease, all across your program, solving multiple issues of the same kind. It also is more readable.

```
def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for x in my_range(1, 2 * CONST, 0.01):
    #do something
```

**[For-loop reference](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)**

Comment: This looks the most correct; both `range` and `xrange` work on integers and a custom range-like generator allows to work around that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Comment: Adding lots of floats together is a recipe for inaccuracy. Following link shows a better way to create a float range: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66472/

Comment: Yes, that way's nice, and it's easy to turn that function into a generator too.

Answer (score 3):

[`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) has a method that can be used to create a range of floats.

```
from numpy import arange

for x in arange(0, 2*CONST, 0.01):
    do_something(x)
```