# Python for loop with small steps

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How can I make an for loop in python with steps of 0.01?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 for X0 in range (-0.02, 0.02, 0.01):
     for Y0 in range (-0.06, 0.09, 0.01):
```

it says 
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.

Comment: See this question if you want to code a `range` function that accepts floats or if you want to use numpy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Answer (score 8):

```
[x * 0.01 for x in xrange(10)]
```

will produce

```
[0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09]
```

Comment: How do I do this with a double loop?

Comment: for X0 in range ([X0 * 0.01 for x in xrange(-2,2)]):

Comment: Just replace "range(...)" by the above list (or other iterator).

Comment: +1 but im recommend using range, not xrange. range in Python 3.x is xrange from Python 2.x.

Comment: @ndpu As you said, `xrange()` in py2 is the same as `range()` in py3, so he's using py3's `range()`... You're recommending him to use what he's already using.

Comment: @ndpu - 2to3 will automatically change xrange->range if you migrate code. you're correct that range should be used in python3 however.

Comment: edit: nevermind, fixed it.. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The python `range` only takes integers as the error message indicates. If you want to use float steps, you can either use numpy's arange or just divide a integer range:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.arange(-0.02, 0.02, 0.01)
array([-0.02, -0.01,  0.  ,  0.01])
```

in your example:

```
for X0 in np.arange(-0.02, 0.02, 0.01):
    for Y0 in np.arange(-0.06, 0.09, 0.01):
```

or:

```
>>> print [a/0.01 - 0.02 for a in range(4)]
[-0.02, -0.01, 0.0, 0.009999999999999998]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a library:

```
def float_range(a,b,c):
    while a < b:
        yield a
        a += c
for X0 in float_range (-0.02, 0.02, 0.01):
    for Y0 in float_range (-0.06, 0.09, 0.01): 
        print X0, Y0
```