# How to create a range of numbers with a given increment

Tags: python, file, list, matlab

I want to know whether there is an equivalent statement in lists to do the following. In MATLAB I would do the following

```
fid = fopen('inc.txt','w')
init =1;inc = 5; final=51;
a = init:inc:final
l = length(a)
for i = 1:l
   fprintf(fid,'%d\n',a(i));
end
fclose(fid);
```

In short I have an initial value, a final value and an increment. I need to create an array (I read it is equivalent to lists in python) and print to a file.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your question.

Comment: @Russel Borogove pardon me. I actually wrote a different question yesterday for which i got an answer. When i changed the question, i did not know that the title would still remain even after a day ;)

Comment: @Vaidyanathan BTW you don't really need the loop in MATLAB. `fprintf(fid,'%d\n', a);` would suffice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python, `range(start, stop + 1, step)` can be used like Matlab's `start:step:stop` command. Unlike Matlab's functionality, however, `range` only works when `start`, `step`, and `stop` are all integers. If you want a parallel function that works with floating-point values, try the `arange` command from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as handle:
    for n in np.arange(1, 5, 0.1):
        handle.write('{}\n'.format(n))
```

Keep in mind that, unlike Matlab, `range` and `np.arange` both expect their arguments in the order `start`, `stop`, then `step`. Also keep in mind that, unlike the Matlab syntax, `range` and `np.arange` both stop as soon as the current value is greater than **or equal to** the stop value.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: this is much more generic. Thank you. What is the difference between `with .. as` and `f.open()\f.close()`. Also like matlab inbuilt tutorials with **examples** for python. In the website it looks a lot more jumbled.

Comment: The `with .. as` construct is basically shorthand for `f.open() .. f.close()`, except that `f.close()` is guaranteed to be called in case of an exception ([examples](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)).

Comment: Python doesn't really have built-in tutorials, but there is one online at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/, and there are are many others written by other folks. Try out a couple to get a feel for things.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create a function for this. The first three arguments of the function will be the range parameters as integers and the last, fourth argument will be the filename, as a string:

```
def range_to_file(init, final, inc, fname):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(init, final, inc)))
```

Now you have to call it, with your custom values:

```
range_to_file(1, 51, 5, 'inc.txt')
```

So your output will be (in the `fname` file):

```
1
6
11
16
21
26
31
36
41
46
```

> ***NOTE:** in Python 2.x a* `range()` *returns a list, in Python 3.x a* `range()` *returns an immutable sequence iterator, and if you want to get a list you have to write* `list(range())`

Answer (score 2):

`test.py` contains :

```
#!/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                  

f = open("test.txt","wb")                                                                                                                                                                           
for i in range(1,50,5):                                                                                                                                                                             
    f.write("%d\n"%i)

f.close()
```

You can execute

python test.py

file `test.txt` would look like this :

```
1
6
11
16
21
26
31
36
41
46
```

Comment: it is prefered to use the `open` function with the `with/as` statement. It will close the file even if an exception occured during the file manipulation.

Comment: @PeterVaro Thanks alot. It worked. Just a question. Say i am reading in float values in contrast to int, for example then the code will be `for i in range(1.5,51.5,5)`. But this throws an error saying `range() integer end argument expected, got float.`

Comment: @Vaidyanathan You may have to build one of your own for `range()` with floats. See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
nums = range(10) #or any list, i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3...]
number_string = ''.join([str(x) for x in nums])
```

The `[str(x) for x in nums]` syntax is called a list comprehension.  It allows you to build a list on the fly.  `'\n'.join(list)` serves to take a list of strings and concatenate them together. `str(x)` is a type cast: it converts an integer to a string.

Alternatively, with a simple for loop:

```
number_string = ''
for num in nums:
    number_string += str(num)
```

The key is that you cast the value to a string before concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the original poster wanted 51 to show up in the list, as well.

The Python syntax for this is a little awkward, because you need to provide for range (or xrange or arange) an upper-limit argument that is one increment beyond your actual desired upper limit.  An easy solution is the following:

```
init = 1
final = 51
inc = 5
with open('inc.txt','w') as myfile:
    for nn in xrange(init, final+inc, inc):
        myfile.write('%d\n'%nn)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open('inc.txt','w').write("\n".join(str(i) for i in range(init,final,inc)))
```

Comment: it is prefered to use the `open` function with the `with/as` statement. It will close the file for you -- even if an exception occured -- which you missed in your code snippet.