# Create a list with n numbers with definite intervals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I need to create a list from 1 to n numbers in a uniform interval.For example, the length of the list is 6 and I need with an interval of 2,it needs to create 6 numbers in uniform intervals. the interval and size of list are dynamic values.

```
l=[1,3,5,7,9,11]
```

I tried np.arange() and np.linespace() but they don't accomplish what I need.I am wondering whether there is any function to do this

Comment: did you look into range?

Comment: `list(range(1, 2*6, 2)) -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]`

Comment: yes but how can I use range for this

Comment: @Samwise why 2*6?6 is the length of list but why 2?

Comment: The usage is `range(start, end, step)`.  The step size is 2, so if the range has 6 elements, the end of the range needs to be 2*6.

Comment: @SriTest see docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: Numpy np.arange works too.  `np.arange(1,2*6,2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a range of numbers with a given increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325312/how-to-create-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-given-increment)

Comment: @Samwise It doesn't work when the length of my list is 13.

Comment: yes it does.  `range(1, 2*13, 2) ->
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25]`

Comment: How did  you use `arange` and `linspace`?  What was wrong with the  result?  Or `range`?

Comment: @Samwise It solved the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do that with np.arange(), but I am unable to get the specifics of your question, but for now, given a dynamic start number, interval value and number of elements for the list, you can do something like

```py
import numpy as np
start = 1
n = 6
interval = 2
l = np.arange(start, interval * n , interval)
```

Else if your start and final number are given, you can edit the above for the same too. The same can be accomplished with range() function too, with the same parameters as above, and

```py
l = list(range(start, interval*n, interval))
```

edit:- you can also do interval*n + 1, if the list has to be inclusive of the number at the end.