# How to get list of the range consisting of floats?

Tags: python

How to get list of the range consisting of floats? Why the below code is not working?

```
lons = list (range(80.0,90.0,0.05))

print (lons)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator function:

```
from math import ceil
def solve(start, end, step):
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986098/846892
    for i in xrange(int(ceil((end-start)/step))):
        yield start + step*i
print list(solve(80.0, 90.0, 0.5))
#[80.0, 80.5, 81.0, 81.5, 82.0, 82.5, 83.0, 83.5, 84.0, 84.5, 85.0, 85.5, 86.0, 86.5, 87.0, 87.5, 88.0, 88.5, 89.0, 89.5]
```

Or using `NumPy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(80., 90., .5)                                                                 
array([ 80. ,  80.5,  81. ,  81.5,  82. ,  82.5,  83. ,  83.5,  84. ,                            
        84.5,  85. ,  85.5,  86. ,  86.5,  87. ,  87.5,  88. ,  88.5,                            
        89. ,  89.5])
```

Comment: Your function suffers from the same round-off errors as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477610/119527).

Answer (score 7):

You can utilise a combination of [takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [count](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) (from 2.7 onwards), if you didn't want to write your own function, eg:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count
my_range = list(takewhile(lambda L: L < 90, count(80, 0.05)))
```

Comment: obviously you'll want to check that min_val <= max_val, otherwise `takewhile` will run infinitely.

Comment: Your function suffers from the same round-off errors as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477610/119527). Even the docs suggest against using floating-point values in `count`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart indeed... put anything that gives a sensible result when `+`'d.... such as a `decimal.Decimal` - the question was how to get a range of floats - this provides that... whether the result is ultimately desirable is another thing :)

Answer (score 2):

From the Python docs for [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

> The arguments must be plain integers.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't help the questioner get a range of floats.

Answer (score 2):

`range` just takes intergers. 
You can form a range and multiply them by floats to get the numbers you require, like this

```
lons = [80+x*0.05 for x in range(0,200)]
```

Be aware you might end up with small rounding "errors" for that many numbers.

Comment: You're not accumulating the floating-point values, so you shouldn't have any round-off error, right?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I got roundoffs on 2.6 but not 2.7

Answer (score 1):

`range` only works for integers. See the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

The functionality you're looking for is:

```
def floatrange(min_val, max_val, step):
    val=min_val
    while val < max_val:
        yield val
        val += step
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own range function to manage floats.

> > > def n_range(x, y, jump):
> > >       ...   while x < y:
> > >       ...     yield x
> > >       ...     x += jump
> > >       ...
> > >       lons = list (n_range(80.0,90.0,0.05))
> > >
> > > print (lons)

Answer (score 1):

Someone I respect once said:

> There's no point in floating point.

So the actual answer to your question is: You're doing it wrong :)

But as that wouldn't exactly count as an answer here on SO, here's a frange function that could work for you. It elevates everything to ints and yields the floats you want.

As you probably can tell by the code, `decpl` stands for "decimal places" and defines the resolution of the floating point argument. I don't think there's an easy way to reliably derive that from the value passed to the `step` argument. (Comments are welcome)

```
def frange(start, stop, step, decpl):
    exp = 10.0 ** decpl
    for i in xrange(int(start * exp), int(stop*exp), int(step*exp)):
        yield i / exp

print list(frange(80, 90, 0.1, 1))
```