# How to count by twos with Python's 'range'

Tags: python, range

So imagine I want to go over a loop from 0 to 100, but skipping the odd numbers (so going "two by two").

```
for x in range(0,100):
    if x%2 == 0:
        print x
```

This fixes it. But imagine I want to do so jumping two numbers? And what about three? Isn't there a way?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the step argument (the last, optional):

```
for x in range(0, 100, 2):
    print(x)
```

Note that if you actually want to **keep** the odd numbers, it becomes:

```
for x in range(1, 100, 2):
    print(x)
```

**[Range](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)** is a **[very](http://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)** **[powerful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value)** **[feature](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&t=3m4s)**.

Comment: You've just edited it, but I guess `step=2` also worked. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde range() doesn't take keyword arguments, in fact

Comment: Ok so that means it wouldn't. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @JuanRocamonde Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde don't forget to accept the answer so that other users can identify it (only if you're actually happy with that)

Comment: Yes once the timer lets me :)

Comment: I think your answer might have a mistake, since `range(1, 100, 2)` starts iterating with `1` and thus skips the _even_ numbers, whereas `range(0, 100, 2)` starts iterating at `0` and thus skips the _odd_ numbers.

Comment: @DavidZ right! non-English speaker, I always confuse odd/even :) answer edited, thanks

Answer (score 3):

**(Applicable to Python <= 2.7.x only)**

In some cases, if you don't want to allocate the memory to a list then you can simply use the xrange() function instead of the range() function. It will also produce the same results, but its implementation is a bit faster.

```
for x in xrange(0,100,2):
    print x,   #For printing in a line

>>> 0, 2, 4, ...., 98
```

[Python 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) actually made `range` behave like `xrange`, which doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(0, 100, 2):
    print i
```

If you are using an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), it tells you syntax:

min, max, step(optional)

Comment: Yep, but I wanted to say about IDE syntax help :P