# Two turtles with random movements

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I just started learning Python from interactivepython.org and am stuck with the below exercise:

> Modify the turtle walk program so that you have two turtles each with a random starting location. Keep the turtles moving until one of them leaves the screen.

This is what I came up with. The program stops with 1 iteration and both turtles start from the same coordinates for some reason.

```
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()

kj = turtle.Turtle()
saklep = turtle.Turtle()    
saklep.color('green')


c = random.randrange(1,100)
v = random.randrange(1,100)
b = random.randrange(1,100)
n = random.randrange(1,100)

kj.setx(c)
kj.sety(v)
saklep.setx(b)
saklep.sety(n)

def isinscreen(t,s,w):

    leftmost=-(w.window_width())/2
    rightmost =(w.window_width())/2
    uppermost = (w.window_height())/2
    bottommost =-(w.window_height())/2


    tx = t.xcor()
    ty = t.ycor()
    sx = s.xcor()
    sy = s.ycor()

    if tx > rightmost or ty >uppermost:
        return False
    elif tx < leftmost or ty < bottommost:
        return False
    elif sx > rightmost or sy > uppermost:
        return False
    elif sx < leftmost or sy < bottommost:
        return False
    else:
        return True


while isinscreen(kj,saklep,wn) == True:
    for i in random.randrange(1,361):
        kj.forward(100)
        kj.left(i)
    for deg in random.randrange(1,361):
        saklep.forward(100)
        saklep.right(deg)

wn.exitonclick()
```

---

Answer (score 4):

I think you're mixing `randrange` with `range`. This line:

```
for i in random.randrange(1,361):
```

Triggers this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable on line 47
```

Because `random.randrange(x,y)` returns an `int` within `x` and `y`. Say for instance `13`. Then what you're trying to do is the same a doing `for i in 13`, which doesn't work [because `for` needs an iterable](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) which `13` is not. You should do this instead:

```
my_random_number = random.randrange(1,361)
for i in range(1, my_random_number)
```

Check this answer for [more informations about range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678156/how-to-count-by-twos-with-pythons-range/27678169#27678169).

---

Same comment for this line:

```
for deg in random.randrange(1,361):
```

---

Concerning the *both turtles start at the same location* problem, actually this is not true: by design, `turtle.Turtle()` seems to initialise a Turtle at location `(0, 0)` **and** draw it immediately. Then, when you assign `kj` and `saklep` some coordinates, it seems to be moving them with an animation.

Try only this portion of your code and you'll see that what I just described is happening:

```
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()

kj = turtle.Turtle()
saklep = turtle.Turtle()    
saklep.color('green')

c = random.randrange(1,100)
v = random.randrange(1,100)
b = random.randrange(1,100)
n = random.randrange(1,100)

kj.setx(c)
kj.sety(v)
saklep.setx(b)
saklep.sety(n)
```

Comment: Any thoughts on the "both turtles start from the same coordinates" problem?

Comment: Thank you. Yes - the turtles seem to move to the x y coordinates after i run the program. how do i move them to different coordinates right at the start?

Comment: @Kunkka I don't know - perhaps by sending keyword arguments to `turtle.Turtle(my_keyword_arg=some_value)` would be the most plausible thing to do but I'd suggest you have a look at the documentation (or the code of the class on github if it's available, in the `__init__` method)