# A bug in Python: np.arange(-0.1, 0.2, 0.1)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I just found a weird thing in Python2/3. It seems it's a bug? 
[image: I only put an example using Python2]

I think np.arange(-0.1, 0.2, 0.1) should give [-0.1, 0., 0.1]? Any explanation?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python decimal range() step value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

"When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases."