# How to create range of numbers in Python like in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, range

Is there any way to create a range of numbers in Python like MATLAB using a simple syntax, i.e, not using loops. For example:

MATLAB:
`a = 1:0.5:10`
give
`a = [1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 .... 9.5 10]`

Comment: use the `range` function

Comment: In the likely event that you're using `numpy`, there's a similar `arange`; note that `range` and `arange` are both half-open, they **exclude the `stop`** (e.g. `np.arange(1, 10, 0.5)` will be `array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  ... ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5])`).

Comment: range didn't work with floating increment, if i use np.arange, then how to include the increment after?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `np.arange` gets you closest to what you are used to from matlab. However, `np.arange` excludes the end point. The solution that you proposed in your own answer can lead to wrong results (see my comment).

This however, will always work:

```
start = 0
stop = 3
step = 0.5
a = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
```

For further reading: Especially if you are an experienced matlab-user, this guide/cheat sheet might be interesting:  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Answer (score 6):

Numpy has `arange` and `r_` which look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.arange(1, 3, .5))
# [ 1.   1.5  2.   2.5]
print(np.r_[1:3:.5])
# [ 1.   1.5  2.   2.5]
```

Notice that it is a little different than matlab, first the order of the stop and step are reversed in numpy compared to matlab, and second the stop is not included the the result. You might also consider using `linspace` it's often preferred over `arange` when you're working with floating point numbers because `num` can be defined more precisely than `step`:

```
print(np.linspace(1, 3, num=5))
# [ 1.   1.5  2.   2.5  3. ]
```

or

```
print(np.linspace(1, 3, num=4, endpoint=False))
# [ 1.   1.5  2.   2.5]
```

Comment: miss parenthesis on `print(np.linspace(1, 3, num=5)` may be `print(np.linspace(1, 3, num=5))` but thanks!!! +1. i solve my problem using `np.append(np.arange(start, stop, step),stop)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1, 10, 0.5)
print (a)
```

Comment: Why would you convert the `array` back to a `list` (and, if you were particularly determined to do so, why `[a for a in ...]` rather than `list(...)`)?!

Comment: I guess he said without using loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
```

doesn't work for all cases!

I explain :

Octave (Matlab) version gives 9 values for this case:

```
clc
start=0
stop=1.2
step=1/7
a = start : step : stop
length(a)
```

It gives:

```
start = 0
stop = 1.2000
step = 0.1429
a =

 Columns 1 through 8:

         0    0.1429    0.2857    0.4286    0.5714    0.7143    0.8571    1.0000

 Column 9:

    1.1429

ans = 9
```

It gives 9 values.

This Python version gives 10 values:

```
start = 0
stop = 1.2
step = 1 / 7
print("step", step)
a = np.arange(start, stop + step, step)
print(a)
print(a.size)
```

gives

```
step 0.14285714285714285
[0.         0.14285714 0.28571429 0.42857143 0.57142857 0.71428571
 0.85714286 1.         1.14285714 1.28571429]
10
```

(Note how 1.28571429 > 1.2)

The solution:

```
def arange_like_matlab_or_octave(a, b, srate):
    k = []
    i = 0
    dt = 1 / srate
    t = a + i * dt
    while t <= b:
        k.append(t)
        i += 1
        t = a + i * dt
    return np.array(k)
```

with this:

```
a = arange_like_matlab_or_octave(start, stop, 1 / step)
```

It gives a numpy array like `np.arange`:

```
[0.         0.14285714 0.28571429 0.42857143 0.57142857 0.71428571
 0.85714286 1.         1.14285714]
9
```

Comment: This is not exactly how the colon operator works in MATLAB. It does something clever to use the end value even if rounding errors make the end value just outside the range. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377235/7328782 — still, nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python's built in `xrange` function can generate integers like so:

```
xrange(start, stop, step)
```

But `xrange` cannot do floats.

Comment: You can with the proper workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value .. however, `numpy.arange` is more elegant.