# Is there better alternative to Numpy arange()?

Tags: python, numpy

For the code below, I want the range to stop at value 1.0, but it keeps going up to 1.099999..., which makes sense as it's a float value.

What would be the better way to create this range with step of 0.1?

```
import numpy as np

start = 0.5
stop = 1.0
step = 0.1

for parameter_value in np.arange(start, stop + step, step):
  print(parameter_value)
```

Output

```
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
1.0999999999999999
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `numpy.linspace`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html . Floating point numbers in general will have the issue you're observing

Comment: You can replace `stop + step` with `stop + epsilon`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141432/python-numpy-machine-epsilon) you can see how to get an `epsilon`

Comment: There's no such thing as 0.1. Not marking as a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your answer, I'm aware of floating point characteristics, mainly I'm looking for other alternatives. I end up using linspace for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not represent 0.1 exactly in binary [IEEE 754](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format, which is what most modern architectures use internally to represent floating point numbers.

The closest binary value to 0.1 is just a shade under truth. When you add this nearest approximation five times, the error will increase.

According to the docs for [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) for these cases.

The reason is that by clamping the ends, `linapace` can make some assurances about the cumulative error which `arange` can not. Each individual step used by `linspace` may not be the closest binary representation of 0.1, but each element will be as close as possible to `n * 0.1` from the start and end.

The `linapace` call corresponding to `np.arange(0.5, 1.1, 0.1)` is

```
np.linspace(0.5, 1.0, 6)
```

The other advantage of `linspace` is that you fix the number of points. Also according to the `arange` docs (the return value):

> For floating point arguments, the length of the result is `ceil((stop - start)/step)`. Because of floating point overflow, this rule may result in the last element of *out* being greater than *stop*.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the fact that division doesn't incur as much error as iterated addition. This is as precise as floating point arithmetic can get you:

```
np.arange(5, 11) / 10.0
# => array([0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

(`np.linspace` uses a very similar formula, though as long as you are working with rational numbers, the code above may be easier to grasp in your use case - you don't have to calculate the number of steps yourself.)

Comment: I like the idea but in this specific case I want an user to input start, stop and step information. I think I will have to do more transformation to use the form.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to know the number of iteration to approch the stop.

With

```
start = 0.5
stop = 1.0
step = 0.1

a = np.arange(start, stop , step)

for parameter_value in a:
    print(parameter_value)
```

It's missing one value.

So it is necessary to do something like that :

```
a = np.arange(start, stop + step , step)
```

but in this case

```
start = -1.0
stop = 0.9799
step = 0.33

a = np.arange(start, stop + step, step)
```

gives

```
-1.0
-0.6699999999999999
-0.33999999999999986
-0.009999999999999787
0.3200000000000003
0.6500000000000004
0.9800000000000004
```

We know that 0.9800 > 0.9799

Even with that

```
a = np.arange(start, stop + step * 1e-3, step)
```

it gives the same bad result

```
-1.0
-0.6699999999999999
-0.33999999999999986
-0.009999999999999787
0.3200000000000003
0.6500000000000004
0.9800000000000004
```

but with

```
a = np.arange(start, stop + step * 1e-4, step)
```

0.9800000000000004 will not be included.

So, here 1e-4 gives no error with a stop whitch contains 2 digit after the comma.

With

```
a = np.arange(start, stop + step * 1e-9, step)
```

it get gives no error with a stop whitch contains 7 digit after the comma.

But in the case of

```
start = 0.5
stop = 1.0
step = 0.1
```

It gives

```
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

It gets somewhat dirty results.

With linspace it is more concise, but it is necessary to know the number of iteration or the number of points in the result.

This function can help:

```
def give_array(start, stop, step):
    n = int((stop - start) / step)  # n jump
    num_points = n + 1
    new_stop = start + n * step
    return np.linspace(start, new_stop, num_points)
```

where n is the number of ieration such that
start + n * step <= stop

With

```
a = give_array(start, stop, step)

for parameter_value in a:
    # print("%.4f" % (parameter_value))
    print(parameter_value)
```

It gives cleaner result :

```
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

Likewise there is also a proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143732/how-to-create-range-of-numbers-in-python-like-in-matlab/77982059#77982059)