# Creating Python List with 0.1 Spacing

Tags: python

I want to create a list such as this one in Python:

```
[0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.]
```

But when I use this method:

```
z = [x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 11)]
```

I get this output:

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
```

How can I create my desired list without these errors?

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Comment: You'll get slightly better accuracy with `[x / 10.0 for x in range(11)]`.  But the real answer is another question: why do you care about these tiny errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors are a fact of life for binary floating point numbers. You can force Python to use decimal arithmetic with the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
import decimal
z = [decimal.Decimal(i) / decimal.Decimal(10) for i in range(0, 11)]
```