# Define python built-in range specialized for a built-in (or not) type

Tags: python

Let's say I implement a class named `MyClass`. I know that it's possible to implement built-in functions specialized behavior for the class that I define. For instance I can implement `MyClass.__repr__` which will be called if I use it on an instance of `MyClass`. Because `range` is also a built-in function, is it possible to implement the specialized behavior of `range` for `MyClass`?

Let's suppose that I have a class on which I know that I can iterate (as like as i know I can iterate over integers). For instance Fraction:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction as F
>>> range(F(0,3),F(3,3),F(1,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Fraction.
```

Obviously I could implement them with a different name. I'm just curious how far the duck typing approach could go.

Edit: The expected behavior for `range(F(0,3),F(3,3),F(1,3))` is to return `[F(0,3), F(1,3), F(2,3)]`.

Edit: So that we do not focalize on Fractions, I give another example. I use a library for physical dimensions (pint). Let's say I want to iterate from 0 seconds to 10 seconds, by 1 second.

```
>>> from pint import UnitRegistry
>>> from numpy import arange
>>> ur = UnitRegistry()
>>> arange(0*ur.s, 10*ur.s, 1*ur.s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
>>> range(0*ur.s, 10*ur.s, 1*ur.s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pint/quantity.py", line 365, in __int__
pint.errors.DimensionalityError: Cannot convert from 'second' to 'dimensionless'
```

Comment: [Python decimal range() step value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477610/2301450)

Comment: Yes ok they define another method named `whatever_range` and it works. I want to know if I can implement it such that when I call `range` it calls my `whatever_range` instead.

Comment: `range = whatever_range`, or change CPython's source code.

Comment: No, I would still need to call this as a class method ... ? I want to use `range(myclass0, myclass1, myclass2)`. And eventually even define `range(myclass0)`.

Comment: Okay, the built-in `range` can't do it.

Comment: This seems to be where they define range in the python code.  Not sure what this entails, but maybe it will help you track down your answer.  =c)
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d741c6d3179b771cec8d47c7b01dd48181b7717e/Objects/rangeobject.c

Comment: `numpy.arange(F(0,3),F(3,3),F(1,3))`, you won't be doing it using pythons range

Comment: Interesting, I guess it's working because numpy specializes arange in case a Fraction type is given to it? But still not exactly what I want

Comment: It works because arange takes floats, interestingly linspace does not give you back anything, unfortunately it is about the closest thing I know of bar doing some hacks of your own to what you are trying to do.

Comment: In you example can you not `units = ur.s.magnitude` then use units in arange? You could also probably implement something by subclassing http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/numpy.html

Comment: Yes I can extract all the magnitudes and iterate over them, but still because it lacks the unit it might not make sense. for instance iterate from 1 centimeter to 1 meter might not work. I could convert all them to centimeters but then it could fail if I pass millimeters. I could convert them to femtometers I guess... but that's not very elegant.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your objects to be interpreted as arguments for `range()`, you can implement `__index__`:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __index__(self):
...         return 123
... 
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> range(x)
range(0, 123)
```

But if you want to customize the behavior of `range()`, then that's not possible. `range()` will only return integers according to the start, stop and step arguments it received. You can see that yourself by looking at [the source for the `range` object](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f9391e2b74a5/Objects/rangeobject.c#l580).

Comment: Does that solve the problem for `fractions.Fraction`?

Comment: Interesting but it's not exactly what I asked since I want range to return an iterator over objects of `MyClass` type.

Comment: @vaultah: fractions are not integral types, it does not make any sense for them to implement `__index__`

Comment: @Emilien: then specify it in the question ;) By the way, it's not possible to do what you want: `range` will return only integers

Comment: Thanks, I specified the expected behavior for Fractions. You can extrapolate to `MyClass`.