# Function for Range for floats in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to define my own floating-point version of range() here.  It works the same as built-in range() function but can accept float values.start, stop, and step are integer or float numbers and step is a non-zero value and it also can be negative.

I have tried looking for answers on stackoverflow but all of them only work for positive step. I keep getting stuck on a test where it tests the value (0,0.25,-1)
I'm a hundred percent sure there is a quicker and faster to implement this because my program takes a long time to test all the values. can someone help me create a function to do this and I Can't user imported tools.

```
def float(start,stop,step):
  x = start
  my_list = []
  if start < stop:
    while x<stop:
        my_list.append(x)
        if x < 0:
            x-=step
        elif x > 0:
            x+=step
        else:
            x+=step
    return my_list
  if start > stop:
    while x<=start and x>stop:
        my_list.append(x)
        if x < 0:
            x=step
        elif x > 0:
            x+=step
        else:
            x+=step
    return my_list
```

Comment: If it is supposed to work like the builtin range function, then you need to put the greater number first if you are going backwards

Comment: Found this answer (and others) http://stackoverflow.com/a/32536460/2308683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you're getting answers wrong is the top level `if` statements are wrong. You don't want to look at the boundaries when deciding which way to move. It's legal to ask for a range that has nothing in it (with e.g. `stop` less than `start` with a positive `step`).

Here's how I'd minimally adjust your code to work properly:

```
def float_range(start,stop,step):
    x = start
    my_list = []
    if step > 0:
        while x < stop:
            my_list.append(x)
            x += step
    else: # should really be if step < 0 with an extra check for step == 0 
        while x > stop:
            my_list.append(x)
            x += step
    return my_list
```

Comment: That should happen automatically if your other check is either removed or changed to `if step < 0`. (You might also want to raise an exception is `step` is zero.)

Comment: Oh, actually I hadn't read all the details of your code. There are some other issues, but the initial bits were right. I'll edit with more fixes.

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked. I had everything misplaced. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Convert the floating steps into integer steps.  You'll get less drift from error due to rounding of floats:

```
def float_range(start,stop,step):
    istop = int((stop-start) // step)
    for i in range(int(istop)):
        yield start + i * step
```