# Why do I get the error: "Float object cannot be interpreted as an integer" in my for loop for calculating integrals

Tags: python, integer

```
def f1(x):
    return(x**2)
n = int(input("input amount of rectangles"));
a = int(input("input starting x"));
b = int(input("input ending x"));
w = ((b-a)/n);
for x in range(a,b,w): #rectangle algorithm for x^2
    area =int((f1(x)*w)) + area
print(area);
```

I never assigned a float value in the program, so why is it giving me this error?

Comment: You do have a float. The result of your `w` will be a float.

Comment: Can I use a float value as the 'step' in a for loops range()?

Comment: Not quite. But read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/python-decimal-range-step-value

Comment: You could use `(b-a)//n` to perform integer division.