# How to prevent float imprecision from affecting numpy.arange?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point

Because [numpy.arange()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) uses `ceil((stop - start)/step)` to determine the number of items, a small float imprecision `(stop = .400000001)` can add an unintended value to the list.

### Example

The first case does not include the stop point **(intended)**

```
>>> print(np.arange(.1,.3,.1))
[0.1 0.2]
```

The second case includes the stop point **(not intended)**

```
>>> print(np.arange(.1,.4,.1))
[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
```

[numpy.linspace()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) fixes this problem, `np.linspace(.1,.4-.1,3)`. but requires you know the number of steps. `np.linspace(start,stop-step,np.ceil((stop-step)/step))` leads to the same incosistencies.

### Question

How can I generate a reliable `float` range without knowing the # of elements in the range?

### Extreme Case

Consider the case  in which I want generate a float index of unknown precision

```
np.arange(2.00(...)001,2.00(...)021,.00(...)001)
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that (stop-start) is a multiple of step?

Comment: Everything I've read seems to indicate that the only viable approach is to subtract some fraction of the step size from the endpoint `print(np.arange(.1,(.4 - step/1000),step))`. I'm not sure you can avoid that but eventually that will fail too

Comment: @user545424 You **are not** guaranteed it's a multiple of step

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks, that's helpful. It is similar to _converting_ to `int` by a multiplier in that you have to estimate a multiplier, `m` that satisfies `(1/step_size) < m <  1/precision_error`

Comment: Where did you get this step value? Why are you in this situation in the first place? You're probably going to end up guessing with tolerances.

Comment: @BrendanFrick exactly. You could always inflate by several orders of magnitude and then divide it back down again (which would be vectorized so not silly overhead) to escape precision issues. But I don't think there's a call-it-and-forget-about-it solution here, I think you'll always have fringe cases.

Comment: @BrendanFrick if you aren't guaranteed that it is a multiple, and you want something that will work for *most* of your examples, can't you just do `np.linspace(start,stop,int(round((stop-start)/step)),endpoint=False)`?

Comment: @user2357112. Good point, the step value in the extreme case will be an semi-arbitrary selection of precision. If `1/step_size` will always be less than `1/precision_error` or the indexing is invalid anyways. Knowing that I can use the _convert to int_ strategy and set `m = 1/stepsize`, assuming `1/step_size` is large enough to avoid precision error

Comment: @user545424 `np.linspace(start,stop,int(round((stop-start)/step)),endpoint=False)` changes the stepsize in cases which multiples are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 6):

Your goal is to calculate what `ceil((stop - start)/step)` would be if the values had been calculated with exact mathematics.

This is impossible to do given **only** floating-point values of `start`, `stop`, and `step` that are the results of operations in which some rounding errors may have occurred. Rounding removes information, and there is simply no way to create information from lack of information.

Therefore, this problem is only solvable if you have additional information about `start`, `stop`, and `step`.

Suppose `step` is exact, but `start` and `stop` have some accumulated errors bounded by `e0` and `e1`. That is, you know `start` is at most `e0` away from its ideal mathematical value (in either direction), and `stop` is at most `e1` away from its ideal value (in either direction). Then the ideal value of `(stop-start)/step` could range from `(stop-start-e0-e1)/step` to `(stop-start+e0+e1)/step` away from its ideal value.

Suppose there is an integer between `(stop-start-e0-e1)/step` to `(stop-start+e0+e1)/step`. Then it is impossible to know whether the ideal `ceil` result should be the lesser integer or the greater just from the floating-point values of `start`, `stop`, and `step` and the bounds `e0` and `e1`.

However, from the examples you have given, the ideal `(stop-start)/step` could be exactly an integer, as in `(.4-.1)/.1`. If so, any non-zero error bounds could result in the error interval straddling an integer, making the problem impossible to solve from the information we have so far.

Therefore, in order to solve the problem, you must have more information than just simple bounds on the errors. You must know, for example, that `(stop-start)/step` is exactly an integer or is otherwise quantized. For example, if you knew that the ideal calculation of the number of steps would produce a multiple of .1, such as 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, or 4.2, but never 4.05, and the errors were sufficiently small that the floating-point calculation `(stop-start)/step` had a final error less than .05, then it would be possible to round `(stop-start)/step` to the nearest qualifying multiple and then to apply `ceil` to that.

If you have such information, you can update the question with what you know about the errors in `start`, `stop`, and `step` (*e.g.*, perhaps each of them is the result of a single conversion from decimal to floating-point) and the possible values of the ideal `(stop-start)/step`. If you do not have such information, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed that `(stop-start)` is a multiple of `step`, then you can use the `decimal` module to compute the number of steps, i.e.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def arange(start, stop, step):
    steps = (Decimal(stop) - Decimal(start))/Decimal(step)

    if steps % 1 != 0:
        raise ValueError("step is not a multiple of stop-start")

    return np.linspace(float(start),float(stop),int(steps),endpoint=False)

print(arange('0.1','0.4','0.1'))
```

Comment: Unless the step is `1./3.` or something else that can't be represented in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an exact representation of your ends and step and if they are rational you can use the `fractions` module:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>>
>>> a = Fraction('1.0000000100000000042')
>>> b = Fraction('1.0000002100000000002')
>>> c = Fraction('0.0000000099999999998') * 5 / 3
>>> 
>>> float(a) + float(c) * np.arange(int((b-a)/c))
array([1.00000001, 1.00000003, 1.00000004, 1.00000006, 1.00000008,
       1.00000009, 1.00000011, 1.00000013, 1.00000014, 1.00000016,
       1.00000018, 1.00000019])
>>>
>>> eps = Fraction(1, 10**100)
>>> b2 = b - eps
>>> float(a) + float(c) * np.arange(int((b2-a)/c))
array([1.00000001, 1.00000003, 1.00000004, 1.00000006, 1.00000008,
       1.00000009, 1.00000011, 1.00000013, 1.00000014, 1.00000016,
       1.00000018])
```

if not you'll have to settle for some form of cutoff:

```
>>> a = 1.0
>>> b = 1.003999999
>>> c = 0.001
>>> 
# cut off at 4 decimals
>>> round(float((b-a)/c), 4)
4.0
# cut off at 6 decimals
>>> round(float((b-a)/c), 6)
3.999999
```

Answer (score -2):

You can round numbers to arbitrary degrees of precision in Python using the `format` function.

For example, if you want the first three digits of `e` after the decimal place, you can run

```
float(format(np.e, '.3f'))
```

Use this to eliminate float imprecisions and you should be go to go.

Comment: `print(np.arange(.1,float(format(.4, '.1f')),.1))`
`print(np.arange(.1,float(format(.3, '.1f')),.1))` yields the same inconsistencies as the original

Comment: This has changed nothing for me when testing on OP's example. That's visual only