# Adjustable range of for loop acording to stepsize

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to ask user to determine step size of a for-loop.
User will write in input a float number, for example `0.2` or `0.5`, but Python does not accept float in for-loop, so we must change it to integer.

```
for i in range (1, 3.5, 0.5): #This is proposal
   print(i)

for i in range (10, 35, 5): #This is the logical term for Python
   print(i/10)
```

If the user write `0.05` the ranges of loop must be `100 to 350 with step size 5` It means we multiplied `1` and `3.5` into `100` or for step size `0.5` we multiplied them into `10`. then how should we do?

I mean when user write `stepseize = 0.00005` we have `5` decimal numbers, so we must multiply `1` and `3.5` into ***a `1` which has `5` zeros in front of it, `100000`***. If user write `stepseize = 0.0042` we have `4` decimal numbers and the we must multiply `1` and `3.5` into `10000`

```
q = 100... # zeroes are in terms of number of decimals
for i in range (1*(q), 3.5*(q), n*q) : #This is the logical term for Python
   print(i/q)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a decimal range() step value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value)

Comment: I definitively recommend using numpy's `arange`. It works similarly to range but can also deal with floats. If you do not want to use other packages, you will have to deal with "the many zeros in front of the number".

Comment: @offeltoffel Thank you, is it slower or there are no differences in its speed with normal usage without numpy?

Comment: @David: numpy is usually faster than most numeric routines in regular python.

Comment: @offeltoffel Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own range generator that wraps the `range()` function but handles floats:

```
def range_floats(start,stop,step):
    f = 0
    while not step.is_integer():
        step *= 10
        f += 10
    return (i / f for i in range(start*f,stop*f,int(step)))
```

---

which works:

```
>>> for i in range_floats(0, 35, 0.5):
...     print(i)
... 
0.0
0.5
1.0
.
.
.
33.5
34.0
34.5
```