# How to add code inside parameters of range( ) function in Python?

Tags: python, range

I am using Python 3.6.5, and what I want is: when my variable `go` is set to 1, my `for i in range()` loop to stop running. However, when I put `for i in range(go = 1)`, it outputs:

```
TypeError: range() does not take keyword arguments
```

UPDATE: 
Here is my full `range()` code:

```
for i in range(go = 1):
  names.append(input(str(i)+": "))
```

UPDATE 2: 
Here was my code before:

```
for i in range(amount):
  names.append(input(str(i)+": "))
```

In this, `amount` is equal to whatever the user inputs, meaning however many names they want to fill.

Comment: try `range(3, 10, 2)` or `range(3, 10)` or `range(10)` to see what it does

Comment: Can you please post your full `for` loop. Perhaps you can just use a `break` statement inside the loop and check what `go` is set to there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a decimal range() step value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value)

Comment: @fafl I know what it does; I just want it to accept keyword arguments.

Comment: @ArihanSharma then you will have to write your own function, `range` does not accept keyword arguments

Comment: sounds like a while loop

Comment: What would this code even do? What would `i` be in each iteration?

Comment: Please look at my *revised* edit.

Comment: Which doesn't have any reference to `go`. So things are even less clear than before. What is `go`, why do you want to pass it to `range`, and what was wrong with the code you had?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is my code before I even had `go`; basically `go` determines when the user clicks my button, called `randomize`. `go`indicates that 'the user has clicked the button, stop asking user input anymore and randomize all of the names'.

Comment: What is this button? Is this a web app or using some GUI framework? How will the code know that `go` has been clicked? This sounds *exactly* like a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a `while` instead of a `for ... in`

example:

```
while go != 1:
    ...
```

Comment: But then how will I break out? It will keep on running that and never get to the part where `go = 1`.

Comment: @ArihanSharma It will break when  you set go to 1 inside the `while`. ex: `go=0; while go != 1: go = int(input('inform go value: '))`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned this sounds like a `while` loop, here is the basic concept you can test for yourself

```
go = 0
while go != 1:
    print('test')
    go = 1
print('test complete')
```

Comment: @ArihanSharma no prob :)