# Writing a for loop with very big or very small numbers in python

Tags: python, numpy

How to write a for loop that values varies from `1e-70` to `1e-10` with arbitrary step like `0.000001`.

```
for i in np.arange (1e-70, 1e-10):
```

or writing a for loop for big values as `1e20` to `1e33`

I didint know what should I search to find the relevant answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a decimal range() step value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value)

Comment: @Sayse it is not duplicate. I am noy saying how to use decimal in for loop. I am saying hot to use very small or very big numbers

Comment: both of which are floats, hence the duplicate.

Comment: @Sayse  this is like you tell me to wirte `for i in range(0.00000000000000000000000000000000001, 0.0000000000000000000000001):` this does not make sense

Comment: Please try to be a bit more specific. What kind of values would you expect in your sequence? Equally-spaced values? Or logarithmically-spaced? Or something else? What would be an example of that "arbitrary step"?

Comment: @jdehesa I wrote a loop between `1e-70` to `1e-20` for instance. a very small values

Comment: The top answer to that question shows exactly how to do that, just replace their numbers with yours... https://stackoverflow.com/a/477635/7203433

Comment: @JoshKarpel  These answers are for small decimals nt for a number which has `70` decimal and more. I wonder how to write this amount of zero in one loop.

Comment: You can just write `np.arange(1e-70, 1e-10, 0.000001)`? But it will only contain `1e-70` because the step that you are proposing (`0.000001`) is larger than the distance between the two extremes. Can you please give an example of what values you would expect to see in your result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a step in [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)() like this:

```
for i in np.aragne(1e-70, 1e-10, 1e-20):
```

But note, if your step is bigger than values range, you'll get only a start of your range. So in case `np.arange(1e-70, 1e-10, step=1e-6)` you'll have only one iteration with `i=1e-70`.

Or if you want to have N equally spaced numbers, you can use [np.linspace()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
for i in np.linspace(1e-70, 1e-10, 1000): # 1000 numbers in [1e-70, 1e-10]
```

P.S. Looking at your question, it seem's that you want to get a sequence like `[1e-70, 1e-69, 1e-68, ...]` instead of  `[1e-70, 1e-70+step, 1e-70+2*step, ...]`.
In it is so, you can do it like this:

```
for i in np.logspace(-70, -10, 61):
```

Answer (score 3):

If your objective is to get`[1e-70, 1e-69, 1e-68,...]`, why not use `np.logspace`?

`np.logspace(-70, -10, 61)`

returns exactly that.