# Increasing the contents of a list by a certain number within a range function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math

Hello how can I make a list of numbers that will increase by an x amount until the range is complete. Like I want `set = [i for i in range(2,11)]` I want the contents of `list` to be increase by 0.1, so its contents are going to go like `[2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3...... etc.]`.

Also how can I only print the contents of set1 of elements from the code below. instead of the outputs being `(2, 1, 1) (2, 1, 2) (2, 2, 1) (2, 2, 2) (3, 1, 1) (3, 1, 2) (3, 2, 1) (3, 2, 2)` it would be`(2) (2) (2) (2) (3) (3) (3) (3)`. Thanks for the help :)

```
import itertools
set1 = [i for i in range(2,4)]
set2 = [i for i in range(1,2)]
set3 = [i for i in range(1,2)]

            
list_set = [set1, set2, set3]
for element in itertools.product(*list_set):
  print(element)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a decimal range() step value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value) The other answers there also include using `range` with a multiplier to get the results needed.

Comment: please ask only one question in a SO post