# Loop to test range of variables and find the best ones in Pyhton

Tags: python

First of all thank you for this amazing space to learn from you all, I have the following question. I created a code that imports data from several APIs and it performs various statistical operations around the data. And it returns 1 result number, which is helpful to see if the model is correct.
The code is built around 4 (or more), static variables. What I want is to create a range of number for each of those variables and test all possible combinations in the code, that returns the top 10 highest result numbers.
it looks like this:

```
#I would want to test i.e. variable_1 in a range from (-0.004 to 0.004 at 0.001 increments), the same for the other variables until I can get the top 10 highest result_number
variable_1 = 0.004
variable_2 = 0.005
variable_3 = 30
result_number = 0

def my_code():
global variable_1, variable_2, variable_3
#perform all the operations utilizing the variables
return result_number
```

Please let me know if it is clear, or if you have any idea how to attack this.
Thank YOU!!

I am new to Python so I am still trying to figure out how to loop and record the highest numbers as it goes. The code is fairly long so it will take a few hours for the simmulation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a decimal step value for range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-do-i-use-a-decimal-step-value-for-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Extracting the maximal result from a loop**

```python
best_result = None
for variable_1 in range(-4, 4, 1):
    result = my_code()
    if best_result is None or best_result > result:
        best_result = result
```

**Iterating over decimals** (numpy solution)

```python
import numpy as np

best_result = None
for variable_1 in np.arange(-0.004, 0.004, 0.001):
    result = my_code()
    if best_result is None or best_result > result:
        best_result = result
```

**Iterating over multiple variables** (numpy & itertools solution)

```python
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

variable_range = np.arange(-0.004, 0.004, 0.001)

best_result = None
for (variable_1, variable_2, variable_3) in product(variable_range, variable_range, variable_range):
    result = my_code()
    if best_result is None or best_result > result:
        best_result = result
```

Of course, if your variables have different ranges, you need to define them separately and use them accordingly in [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: This is very helpful!!! How would you record as you go which variables achieved that result. As I mentioned it would have to iterate through all the variables and their possible combinations.

Comment: @PythonNoob Declare an empty list outside the loop, say `best_results = []` and inside the if-statement store the variable-result combination as a tuple in the list, like `best_results.append((variable_1, variable_2, variable_3, result))`

Comment: @PythonNoob consider upvoting the answer and accepting it as the solution if it solved your problem

Comment: KeyError has nothing to do with any code you or I posted. This is a new question and thus requires a new thread

Comment: You are absolutely right. either way this was incredibly helpful! thank you Alex!

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy to create lists of values with decimals, then you can check if the value is in this list:

```
import numpy as np

variable_1 = 0.004
variable_2 = 0.005
variable_3 = 30
result_number = 0

def my_code():
    global variable_1, variable_2, variable_3
    result_number = 0
    result_number += variable_1 in  np.arange(-0.004,0.005,0.001)
    result_number += variable_2 in  np.arange(-0.004,0.005,0.001)
    result_number += variable_3 in  np.arange(22,28,1)
    return result_number


my_code()
```

Something like this. To take in account:

`np.arange(start,stop,step)` create an array like: `[start,start+step,start+2*step,... start+k*step]` until `start+k*step<stop` so, you have to select `stop>` 'your last value seeked' (in your example `stop>0.004` -> `stop = 0.005`)